# Uploading a font and displaying a preview in php/codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, fonts, upload

I am not too great with PHP but I was wondering if there is a way to do this. What I have is a form that allows a user to upload font files and after they have been uploaded it then displays them below in a library. I would like it to actually show an image of what the font looks like in the library. So far I haven't been able to find a way to do this. Is this possible with PHP?

Comment: Have a look at the image drawing functions in PHP. Once the font is uploaded to your server you can use it in image generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a very quick and dirty solution using Code Igniter you can use the Image Manipulation Class and Image Watermarking feature.

Checkout [the documentation of codeigniter 3](http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html) it shows you how to apply a watermark using a custom font. Upload a plain white image source file and open it:

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']     = 75;
$config['height']   = 50;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

Once you have done that then you can draw a watermark on the image:

```
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['wm_text'] = 'Text to Display Here';
$config['wm_type'] = 'text';
$config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf'; // Path to font file
$config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
$config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
$config['wm_padding'] = '20';

$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 

$this->image_lib->watermark();
```

I think everything is either explained here (above) or on the code igniter documentation page.